Unwanted paragraph symbol in "Awesome Sphinx Theme"
I just started working on Sphinx documentation and I'm using "Awesome Sphinx Theme". I just happened to realize that there are unwanted "paragraph" symbol keep on appearing on the title header and I just don't know how to remove it.

import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))

project = 'Test'
copyright = '2024, John'
author = 'John'
release = '0.1.0'

extensions = ["sphinxawesome_theme.highlighting"]

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

html_theme = 'sphinxawesome_theme'
html_title = f'{project}'
html_static_path = ['_static']

I've also attached my conf.py for reference. Any help would be appreciated.

There are two Sphinx variables that control this: html_permalinks, which expects a boolean, and html_permalinks_icon, which expects a string.
html_permalinks = True
html_permalinks_icon = "¶"

html_permalinks_icon controls the inner content of the "permalink" <a> element. An empty string effectively makes it invisible. To remove the element entirely, set html_permalinks to False
This variable is inserted as-is, so you can also use HTML and/or SVG:
from sphinxawesome_theme.postprocess import Icons

html_permalinks_icon = Icons.permalinks_icon  # SVG as a string

The above is rendered as follow (from sphinxawesome.xyz):


Thank you so much @InSync! That actually worked. I just realized that it was part of the documentation and I overlooked it. My bad. Can I know how you managed to get the documentation for the 'sphinxawesome_theme' modules? I don't see it anywhere.

@MaheswarhaRajagopal See this page and other links on the sidebar.
